# CSS Can’t I transition border-style?

Tags: css, border, css-transitions

I have a menu where the elements have a simple animation on hover, changing background color and text color.

Since the element has a border with outset style, I would like to change it to inset to make it look coming forward. However the transition doesn’t seem to work for the border-style property, so the final effect doesn’t look very well, as the change in border style happens immediately and only later the background changes.

Any ideas how to make this work? I found it strange that border-style can‘t be transitioned. If so, any turnaround?

Here’s the code:

```
#main_menu a, #main_menu li { 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
 } /*Hover animation */

#main_menu li:hover { background: #4488CC;  border-style: inset; }

#main_menu li {
        /*GRAPHICS*/
    list-style: none;
    border: 3px outset #496181;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #333;
```

PS: I don’t want to use jquery for this

Answer (score 0):

Your question may have been hastily written, but I think you're missing an `_` in the first selector. Also, it seems that you're animating the `border-style` from `outset` to `outset`, so you won't see any differences. It does indeed work, I've created a demo that changes the `border-color` on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/yPMda/) for you to take a look at.

Comment: You’re right, I’ve corrected the example (guess I messed the things up when writing the minimal version to post). The code works indeed, the only thing is that border-style change is abrupt (you can see that border-style changes from inset to outset immediately, while the other changes follow the transition rules), as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yPMda/1/ The final effect is not really smooth, in my opinion.

Comment: However, I just came to realize that probably you can’t transition border-style, since there are not intermediate statuses. So probably I just have to look for alternative solutions. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create the border as a button image and stretch it in the div and just use box-shadow.  That way your user will still see a smooth button movement by the transition in the shadow.